# Зачем нужен CSS reset?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Зачем нужен этот кусок кода?

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: вы вообще сами пытались это написать в css ? были ли после этого какие то  изменения ? изменились ли отступы ?

Comment: сбрасывает стандартные стили браузера

Comment: Именно "библиотека" [`reset.css`](https://habr.com/ru/post/45296/) нужная для сброса стилей у определённых элементов. А именно данная запись сбрасывается [внешние](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin) и [внутренние](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding) отступы [у всех](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/universal) элементов.

Comment: Не нужен. Я его в своих проектах не использую

Answer (score 2):

Данные строки кода убирают автоматические отступы, предусмотренные в браузерах. На первом примере применяется данный код, на втором - нет.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

`margin` и `padding`: отступы. Их отличие в том, что `padding` - пространство внутри HTML-элемента. `margin` - пространство вокруг границы элементов. Стандартно они не равны 0, а этот код задает им значение `0`. Обычно это очень помогает при верстке